# How to pagination for table list using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, pagination

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="example2_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example2_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="example2_previous">
                    <a href="#" aria-controls="example2" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="paginate_button active"><a href="" aria-controls="example2" ng click="paginationList(1)" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is my html and how to display numbers from 1 to 5 dynamically, if  i have 50 items  in my list

Comment: Do you know you should accept best answer to make community effective, if somebody searching same problem they will see the best answer first. Please accept one of below answers –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
| limitTo : query.limit : (query.page-1)*query.limit"
```

You can use `limitTo` over `ng-repeat` of the list or table.

```
$scope.query = {
   page : 1,
   limit : 20
};

$scope.previousPage = function(){
    $scope.query.page = $scope.query.page - 1;
}
$scope.nextPage = function(){
    $scope.query.page = $scope.query.page + 1;
}
```

And You can put the validation for first and last page.

Comment: Does this answers your question ?